# Pandas dataframe.to_sql cuts part of text value when inserting many rows

Tags: python, postgresql, pandas

I'm inserting large dataframe to my PostgreSQL table using pandas to_sql function. Problem is, that when I have a long text value in one of the columns it gets cut. 
So instead of:

"3432711,3432712,3432713,3432715,3432716,3432718,3432719,3432720,3432721,3432722,3432724,3432725,3432726,3432727,3432729,3432730,3432731,3432732,3432733,3432734,3432736,3432737,3432739,3432740,3432741,3432742,3432743,3432744,3432745,3432746,3432747,3432748,3432749,3432750,3432751,3842395,3842396,3842397"

it only inserts:

"3432711,3432712,3432713,3432715,3432716,3432718,3432719,3432720,3432721,3432722,3432724,3432725,3432726,3432727,3432729,3432730,3432731,3432732,3432733,3432734,3432736,3432737,3432739,3432740,3432741,3432742,3432743,3432744,3432745,3432746,3432747,3432748,"

When I'm trying to insert just one row of dataframe containing this data everyting is good, and whole text value is inserted.

This is part of the code that I use:

```
df = pd.read_sql(sql_statement, connection)
engine = create_engine('postgresql://postgres:xxx@localhost:xxxx/' + dbName)
df.to_sql(tableName, engine, if_exists='append')
```

Any ideas why it is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: You might want to show the schema of the table too. Most likely that column has a max VARCHAR length

Comment: I have to admit that I do not know anything about postgresql or to be honest databases in general - but that said I see that the inserted text is exactly 256 characters long. Could it be possible, that there is a restriction for entries regarding length in the target table ...?

Comment: Problem is that it don't have max VARCHAR length set - it's a text column. And as I mentioned - when I'm inserting only one row containing this long text it is inserted properly, only when I'm inserting whole dataframe (about 50000 rows) it gets cut.